# Convert unicode value to string in the dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to convert the unicode value to string in the dictionary, for that i have write a script to convert the value in string like

```
value = {'a':u'a','b':u'ó'}
for key,valu in  zip(value.keys(),value.values()):
    if type(valu) is unicode:
        print " unicode",valu
        val=valu.encode('utf-8')
        print " encode value",val
        value[key] = val
print "dictionary return value ",value
```

but it gives unexpected out put

```
{'a': 'a', 'b': '\xc3\xb3'}
```

but it should be like

```
{'a': 'a', 'b': 'ó'}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: A `str` cannot contain unicode characters like `ó`. It can contain a UTF-8 encoding of unicode, but that's going to print as a sequence of weird bytes instead of unicode. Unless you specifically care about encodings, for serialization or something, you probably don't want to do this.

Comment: @user2357112: Haidro asked you a question. You should answer it.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: Wrong guy. Understandable mistake, though - our usernames look very similar.

Comment: Oups, sorry, I didn't notice that it autocompleted incorrcetly.

Answer (score 4):

Wait, what?

> I am trying to convert the unicode value to string in the dictionary

OK

> for that i have write a script to convert the value in string like

```
value = {'a':u'a','b':u'ó'}
```

But that maps from a string value to a unicode value, not from unicode to string. And calling the mapping "value" is not really a very good choice.

```
for key,valu in  zip(value.keys(),value.values()):
```

This can be written as

```
for k, v in value.items():
```

The next bit is weird:

```
if type(valu) is unicode:
```

Isn't it always? You entered only unicode values in the dict, why check?

```
    val=valu.encode('utf-8')
```

OK, and now you made it a string. I don't understand why.

```
    value[key] = val
```

So now you value is a mapping from string to string. Is that what you wanted?

> but it gives unexpected out put
>   `{'a': 'a', 'b': '\xc3\xb3'}`

No, that's very much the expected output from the above code. What you actually want to do is unclear. You said you wanted to convert from unicode to string, and you have done that with the unicode values, so maybe this *is* what you want. It's unclear to me.

> but it should be like 
>   `{'a': 'a', 'b': 'ó'}`

Then you need to use Python 3. :-)

I'd recommend that you look through the top questions in the unicode+python tag:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+unicode

And also my blog post on what Unicode is: http://regebro.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/unconfusing-unicode-what-is-unicode/

Comment: But i am also trying to string (ascii) value convert in string(latin)value

Comment: @user2575232: ascii is a subset of latin, so no conversion necessary. I think you should step back from the problem you have now, and tell us what you are trying to achieve, because whatever it is, you are doing it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

That's it. You have converted the unicode value to string successfully.

Since it's a non-ASCII character, `value[b]`'s value is `'\xc3\xb3'` which is the utf-8 literal for ó.

If you use print,

```
>>> print value[b]
>>> ó
```

This is because `print` attempts to display the non-ASCII character by encoding the Unicode string.

Consider this:

```
>>> abc = 'ó'
>>> abc
'\xc3\xb3'
>>> print abc
ó
```